# JasperReport: sum fields disappear after xls sorting

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have such xls file generated by jasper:

[image]

**sum** fields has following jrxml properties:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="1050" y="13" width="90" height="11" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="a41d8696-c8a2-43bc-a41c-1bfe5499d3d4"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
        <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
        <paragraph lineSpacing="1_1_2"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression>##my_experssion##</textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

After I sort by column I sum fields disappear

[image]

Is there any simple way to fix this?

Comment: For some reason field high of **sum** row minimizes to 0.

Comment: So it doesn't disappear, it collapses